# Used mbr2gpt tool on a (I think) non-UEFI machine, can't boot anymore

Tags: boot, bios, uefi, mbr, gpt

I found out that an old desktop I had is still working. Last time it was used it had Windows 10 installed, although the hardware is almost 10 years old. I decide I want to have a dual boot with Windows 10 and Debian 10. I have a bootable pen drive with Debian 10 I used last month on my new laptop, so I stick it in. I can't boot from the USB. I read somewhere I should use switch from BIOS to UEFI to boot from USB and that I should use the tool `mbr2gpt` for that, since there's no UEFI option in the BIOS settings. I open a command line in Windows and run:

```
mbr2gpt /validate

mbr2gpt /convert
```

When I restart the computer, nothing boots anymore, it just goes to a black screen.

edit: It seems I should have checked if the system supports UEFI before using the mbr2gpt tool, but now it's done.

Comment: Mount the disc as secondary on another windows PC and use this tool>>>>>https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/convert-gpt-disk-to-mbr-disk.html

Comment: @Moab but will it boot with the partition table simply changed to MBR? what about the changes needed to the boot loader and BCD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no really supported way of going back from UEFI to MBR. You can probably recreate the MBR partition table and repurpose the partitions as normal MBR partitions, but the BIOS boot code needed in sector 0 and in the boot partition (which will have been rewritten into a EFI System Partition) is not there anymore. Apart from reinstalling, I wouldn’t know where to begin.

About the USB key not being able to boot on that computer: does the key not appear in the boot selection at all, or does it appear, but when booting from it, you get a "No bootable device" or "Operating System not found" (or similar) message? How did you create that bootable Debian 10 pen drive? By dumping a Hybrid ISO/FAT image on it, or using some other tool? With that info (or a link to the ISO/FAT image in question), one could determine if the USB key should be able to boot regular BIOS or if it is UEFI only.

Comment: How about a Windows 10 repair?

Comment: @Ro-ee, I don't really need to save any data, so I would not mind having to reset the system and losing anything. I just need to make it work again, so I can reinstall Windows and Debian.

Comment: About the USB: I have two other laptops with Windows and Ubuntu. I downloaded the Debian 10 .iso and put it in the USB using the Startup Disk Creator tool from Ubuntu. I also tried to create the bootable USB using Rufus, on the Windows laptop. No success.

Comment: About the USB option on the desktop: when I enter the BIOS settings, it seems it's a fairly old BIOS (different from the others I've seen at least). There's no mention of UEFI anywhere. There's no option do disable or enable fast or secure boot. I can send pictures if it helps. What I can see is a 'boot order' option, but only showing the HD, the DVD driver and a "Floppy Driver"

Comment: does it show some sort of USB disk in the BIOS boot order? Sometimes it’s behind USB HDD, USB Floppy. With some BIOSes, certain types of USB sticks are not recognized. I think it would be best to install Windows fresh, but leaving enough space for future Debian partitions. After installing Windows, you can then install debian on the remainder, and set the boot loader (GRUB) up to boot Debian and chainload Windows.