# Can I convert my disk from MBR to GPT and BIOS to UEFI(hp laptop 15-ra0xx)

Tags: bios, uefi, mbr, gpt, efi

So hello everyone!
my laptop has MBR disk and BIOS but on boot menu it also shows boot from EFI file. Does my laptop support UEFI? And if so how do I convert it?

hp laptop 15-ra0xx

Thank you!

Comment: What did your Google search turn up? Have you tried it? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: If the bios is not uefi currently, no you cannot update the bios to support it.

Comment: Best I can tell it does have a uefi bios. Why do you want to convert it?

Comment: @Moab because I need more partitions. Anyways I found a tutorial with mbr2gpt hope it solves my issue

Comment: Read this first>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1570820/used-mbr2gpt-tool-on-a-i-think-non-uefi-machine-cant-boot-anymore

Comment: my laptop has secure boot but its disabled and legacy support enabled